# Auto upload data source from Jedox to Tableau Server

Tags: aws-lambda, automation, tableau-api

This is a real business case and please see details below:

Background:

1. User aims to have not less than 3 times data update for their tableau project.
2. User has scheduled hyper file /csv generation on Jedox side and wish to automate the process of publishing the data to tableau server as data source,
3. The file will be multi table storage file

Experiment requirements:

1. Able to receive notification from Jedox on ‘file generation completed’
   Receive files from Jedox
2. Automatically publish to tableau server as data source
3. After publishment, for the workbooks which are using this data source, their original relationship (joining etc) shall remain the same

I found no clue on Jedox's developer website, and I'm thinking if building some Amazon Lamba package with python or other solution will achieve this? I'm more on tableau visualization developing so have no clue on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from a Jedox OLAP cube into Tableau, you can have a look at the [Jedox OData Hub](https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/integration/odata-hub/odata-tableau.htm). You could use that to read the cube data in Tableau and schedule a refresh.